# ValidationException: Query condition missed key schema element

Tags: python, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I have that item into my dynamodb
[image]

My table was built like this:
[image]

Now I need to make a query using PK and SK.

When I do that, it returns correctly
[image]

But when I put the SK in the query, it generates the title error

```
 result = self.table.query(
            KeyConditionExpression=(Key("PK").eq(where["PK"]) and Key("SK").gt(where["SK"])),
            **kwargs,
        )
```

How do I stop this error? The PK is in the query already.

Answer (score 3):

```
 result = self.table.query(
            KeyConditionExpression=(Key("PK").eq(where["PK"]) and Key("SK").gt(where["SK"])),
            **kwargs,
        )
```

should be

```
 result = self.table.query(
            KeyConditionExpression=(Key("PK").eq(where["PK"]) & Key("SK").gt(where["SK"])),
            **kwargs,
        )
```

The DynamoDB conditions only support the `&` operator and not the `and` operator. In fact, it is not possible to overload the `and` operator in Python.